# IE9 showing SCRIPT601: Unknown runtime error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In IE9 for innerHTML it shows SCRIPT601: Unknown runtime error

the data i am inserting is below. All the tags are closed . I guess the form tag is causing problems but I want It there

```
 getHtmlStr='   <p></p>
    <div id="rs_div"></div>
    <form id="documentDetails" name="documentDetails"></form>
    <p></p>
    <div class="portlet magazines_details" id="magazines">
    <div class="content" id="doc_content">
    <div class="transcript" id="transcript">
    <div class="document-text">
    <p>Many people believe that a spin in a washing machine turns dirty clothes sparkly clean. Aarthi Shankar did too, until she came across a study by Charles Gerba, a microbiologist at the University of Arizona, which showed that household washers contain a shocking amount of bacteria.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div> ';

document.getElementById("notesdiv_"+html[i][0]).innerHTML = getHtmlStr;
```

"notesdiv_"+html[i][0] is id to some div

Comment: Give some more info. Where do you want to insert data below and what is the task of JS as you tagged

Comment: You really need to who us the code where you set the `innerHTML`

Comment: Actually this data is coming from a html editor and this gets added to a div for displaying the content